# Can you use the Cauchy product to multiply two polynomials?

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials

Cauchy Product is used for multiplying series but can it be applied to multiplication of polynomials?

Comment: sure; a polynomial is a series that terminates

Comment: but from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product):  The Cauchy product may apply to infinite series or power series. When people apply it to finite sequences or finite series, it is by abuse of language: they actually refer to discrete convolution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cauchy Products are typically reserved for multiplying infinite series or power series. When multiplying two finite sequences or series, i.e., the polynomials in question, it would be more appropriate to refer to this operation as discrete convolution.